How to write a type that allows arbitrary index access whose value cannot possibly be undefined?
If we enable the noUncheckedIndexedAccess option of TypeScript,
when we try to access the property of an object with arbitrary keys, the type of the value is whatever type you specified and undefined.
This behavior is fine because it match what you can expect to encounter at runtime but,
I would like to be able to specify that there's no way to get undefined ensuring that every property access is safe.
Example snippet
type ArbitraryStringIndexAccess = {
  [key: string]: number
}

const object: ArbitraryStringIndexAccess = {}

const value: number = object.property
// Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
// (2322)

I tried searching myself posible solutions but no luck.
I would like to know if there is a way to do it while keeping the flag.
Edit:
It seems there is an issue already for this in GitHub but it seems
it isn't getting too much attention
noUncheckedIndexAccess - disable per type or property (use case: dynamic Proxy which returns value for every prop)

You can't, that's the whole point of --noUncheckedIndexedAccess. If you don't want that behavior, don't enable that option. I'm confused about how you'd expect anything different. If I were trying this, I'd consider leaving the option off and then adding undefined to any index signatures that need them.

@jcalz I have enabled the option because I think it is good to have since it represents correctly the actual behavior of the code, but for my case I would like to explicitly defined somehow that in this case there's no way you can get undefined.

Your code example as written above demonstrates pretty clearly that you can get undefined. Indeed that's what will happen if you run it. Right now it seems like you're saying "I installed a smoke detector, but how do I let it know that if I'm cooking dinner it shouldn't complain? And no, I don't want to push the button on it to silence it when I'm cooking dinner. And no, I don't want to turn off the smoke detector.  Here's an example: burns down house"  Could you [edit] the question to make this make more sense?

@jcalz It's true that in this example it doesn't make sense but I just showed it like this to illustrate what I want, my actual code involves a Proxy in which you can access any property and it will always give you a value.

It doesn't illustrate what you want, though. It illustrates the opposite. Please [edit] the question to make this make sense. Maybe you could write a Proxy example if that's what you need. But again: no, this is not possible. Does that fully address the question? If so I or someone could write an answer, even though you don't like the answer. If not, what are we missing?

Yeah, I just wanted to know if it is possible and how, if not then that's fine. I don't really want to solve this in any other way, that's why I didn't post the true example because I don't want suggestion to write the code in some other way.

Okay, but your example is literally the opposite of what you're talking about. So not only will you get answers saying "you can't do that", you'll get answers saying "and you shouldn't try." I don't see why that's worse than a suggested workaround for a Proxy, but that's your prerogative. I'll probably write an answer when I get a chance.


I would like to be able to specify that there's no way to get undefined ensuring that every property access is safe.

How do you know that?
Do you know this because you have some exotic object that can actually be indexed by every string? That seems rather exotic, given that there are infinitely many strings, but computer memory is finite, so TypeScript can not currently express this.
Or do you know this because you are only ever indexing with certain strings? Then you should restrict the index signature accordingly:
type Outcome = "ok" | "fail";
const colorFor: {[O in Outcome]: string} = {
  ok: 'green',
  fail: 'red',
}

let outcome: Outcome = 'ok';
const color: string = colorFor[outcome]; // undefined is not possible because 
                                         // every outcome is known to be mapped

Or do you know something beyond the compiler's ability to understand? Then you can use a non-null assertion:
const color: string = o[k]!; // undefined is impossible because you say so

though if you are mistaken, this can cause color to become undefined at runtime.

I didn't mention my use case because I just wanted an answer to the question and not a way around it that requires changes to code. My use case is a Proxy object which can give a non undefined value for every access, the same use case mentioned is the GitHub issue.

This is not currently possible in TypeScript. The effect of enabling the --noUncheckedIndexedAccess compiler option is to add undefined to the read type of index signatures. That's the point. And while there may be some use for disabling this on a per-type basis (such as modeling the behavior of a Proxy whose get handler returns a value always), there hasn't been anywhere near enough community demand to implement that.  There's a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#47594 asking for such support, but it's listed as "Awaiting More Feedback" meaning they need to hear more from the community before they'd think seriously about implementing it.
For now, you can either:

disable the flag and manually add undefined to places you need to see it
use the flag and manually use non-null assertions (!) any time you read from the Proxy
refactor your approach away from a Proxy and toward something with a get() method like { get(key: string): number }, which is friendlier to the type system and possibly friendlier to users, because most people do not expect an object to have a property at arbitrary keys.

